# About a website installing an executable by using Java or JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, security, browser

Is it possible for a web site that uses either Java or Javascript to accomplish the installation (meaning: not just forced download) of an executable on a client Windows system (Windows 7 or newer) when user clicks on only one link on the website?

So in this scenario, the user clicks on a link (e.g. some click-bait link) that is supposed to display some article or a video, on a website. Can this sole single click lead to both a forced download and actual installation of an executable on the users machine?

I do not need, nor am I looking for, explicit detail on how this is done. I am more curious of whether this is even possible with the current Windows OS. In this case the user would be using a recent version of one of the following browsers: IE, FF, Chrome, or Opera.

Comment: Imagine if it was possible. Would you even dare browsing the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about a drive by downloader?

The answer is yes these in java are called applets. Here is come HTML from a webclient what uses an applet.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Your Webclient</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<applet name="yourclientname" width="765" height="503" archive="client.jar" code="client.class">
<param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx1024m">
</applet>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

For a hacker to do it all they need to do is change the .jar and .class in the above. And Java will prompt you to ask if you want to run the applet once you click yes it will run java code normally a dropper. Btw most hackers don't install stuff they either sneak into registry or they simply put a copy of their exe or .jar into your startup folder.

You will have a chance to say no as stated above its just an allow or disallow option. The rest of the HTML can be used to load a picture or whatever. Here is what the allow screen looks like, 
http://openigloo.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/signed-applet.jpg

Comment: Thanks Invexity, but would it actually be possible to "simply put a copy of their exe or .jar into your startup folder." with Windows 7 and newer? I do remember seeing this type of thing on a friends computer in 2001 (result of porn surfing activity) but would it still be possible in today's systems without somehow asking the user to accept the download?

Comment: Well unless you already accepted something at an earlier date that is just a dropper. Then no you can't just force a virus on someone's computer without tricking them to accept something first. If you ask me what I would do if I was a hacker is I would make a website with an img that loads when you accept a java applet to run (so people think it does something) and the applet drops a downloader with no real virus like activity (java is not scanned for viruses). The Java program will connect to a server which just tell it to download stuff.